# How to implement SSO when using OpenID

Tags: oauth, openid, single-sign-on

I have to implement SSO for all our enterprise apps. The apps may reside on different domains. We control the codebase for all the apps, and they can be modified.

We are also implementing OpenID login for all the apps, where if a user tries to access any of the apps, they will be automatically redirected to a custom openid provider. The OP endpoint will be hardcoded, and all user will be redirected to this provider for authentication.

Now one challenge we are facing is to how also implement SSO. We would like that if a user is once logged in, then he should not have to log in again for another application. How do we do that ?

Any pointers on this can be accomplished?

Thanks,
Murtaza